# Conversion to CNF - eliminate implications

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

On the web I found a solution to an exercise on resoulution. Basically, it asks to use resolution refutation to prove
$$ (P \Rightarrow (Q \Rightarrow R)) \Rightarrow ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow R))$$

It proceed converting the sentence into CNF and on the first step the sentence above is translated into
$$ \neg (\neg (P \Rightarrow (Q\Rightarrow R))) \Rightarrow ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow R))$$

What kind of translation is this? Is it an error? Doesn't $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta $ translates into $\neg \alpha \lor \beta $?

My first step is like
$$ \neg (\neg (P \lor (\neg Q \lor R))) \lor (\neg(\neg P \lor Q) \lor (\neg P \lor R))$$
but I don't know if it is right.

Comment: $\alpha$ has been translated into $\neg (\neg \alpha)$

Comment: @Henry now I see, maybe it's too late here for logic reasoning :D However, is my different first step right? What about the proof?

Comment: @Henry WolphramAlpha returns identical results for the evaluation of [first expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CNF%20%28P%20%3D%3E%20%28Q%20%3D%3E%20R%29%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%28P%20%3D%3E%20Q%29%20%3D%3E%20%28P%20%3D%3E%20R%20%29%29) and [my first step](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CNF+~%28~P+%7C%7C+%28~Q+%7C%7C+R%29%29+%7C%7C+~%28~P+%7C%7C+Q%29+%7C%7C+%28+~P+%7C%7C+R%29%29), but different ones for the [book first step](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CNF+~%28~%28P+%3D%3E+%28Q+%3D%3E+R%29%29%29+%3D%3E+%28%28P+%3D%3E+Q%29+%3D%3E+%28P+%3D%3E+R+%29%29)

Comment: well, look closer it seems that it fails to translate the book first step. So, I'm not the only one who haven't understand this simplification :)

Answer (score 0):

For a proof by refutation you need to derive the empty clause by resolution.

I use Polish/Lukasiewicz notation.  So, we have

```
1. C CpCqr C Cpq Cpr.
```

We negate it yielding

```
2. N C CpCqr C Cpq Cpr.
```

Then we get rid of all the conditionals by replacing "C" with "AN", since Cxy==ANxy.

```
3. N AN ANpANqr AN ANpq ANpr.
```

Then by a De Morgan/Petrus Hispanus law NANxy==KxNy we have

```
4. K ANpANqr NAN ANpq ANpr.
```

By the same law we have

```
5. K ANpANqr K ANpq NANpr.
```

And using the same law we then have

```
6. K ANpANqr K ANpq KpNr.
```

Then discharging the conjunctions we have four assumptions:

```
Assumption 1 ANpANqr.
Assumption 2 ANpq.
Assumption 3 p.
Assumption 4 Nr.
```

And now applying resolution we will derive the empty clause which I'll denote by "0":

```
Res. 1, 2  5 ANpr.
Res. 3, 5  6 r.
Res. 4, 6  7 0.
```

Thus, N C CpCqr C Cpq Cpr is unsatisfiable, and therefore CCpCqrCCpqCpr is satisfiable.

Comment: lot of interesting stuffs...at least, it seems. I can't understand your notation at all :(

Comment: @tigerjack89 Cpq in an infix notation is (p$\rightarrow$q).  Apq in the same notation is (p$\lor$q).  Np is $\lnot$p.  Kpq is (p$\land$q).

Comment: Thus, if we start with (P⇒(Q⇒R))⇒((P⇒Q)⇒(P⇒R)), we can abuse notation a bit and write (P⇒"Cqr")⇒("Cpq"⇒"Cpr"), then CpCqr⇒CCpq Cpr and then finally C CpCqr CCpqCpr.